# Unterminated `s' command using sed

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, sed, subprocess

```
a=subprocess.check_output('''grep "MaxSessions" /etc/ssh/sshd_config ''',shell=True)

subprocess.call('''sed -i "s/'{}'/'#MaxSessions 100'/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config'''.format(a),shell=True)
```

Running this command gives the error unterminated s command.
I have checked all the possible combinations of inverted commas.
where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you want to solve stuff using bash commands, why do you write a Python script instead of a Shell script?

Comment: You have to escape `'` using `\'`

Comment: What does `a` hold? Try `'''sed -i "s~'{}'~'#MaxSessions 100'~g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config'''`. An example of the text you are searching for matches in would also help.

Comment: Not more than a guess - do we have to escape the `#` here, too?

Comment: a actually holds #MaxSessions 10. actually I have to find number of connections i.e, maxsesssions which is 10 and if less than 100, I have to make it 100